# is it possible to develop turn by turn navigation for ios app?

Tags: ios, navigation, gps

I am trying to develop turn by turn navigation app for iphone and ipad.
I have been searching these whole day but it seemed like there is no way to build it without having map data api. (I don't think google map provides that api)
Although I can launch google map app in my app but I would like to do it without using google map app. (without using [UIApplication sharedapplicaiton] openURl...etc)

I just would like to ask if it is possible and feasible to build an ios turn by turn navigation app.
Thank you very much

Comment: There is a google maps API that would be possible and feasible to use for turn by turn navigation app except that using the API for turn-by-turn navigation is strictly prohibited by the google maps API terms of usage. Check out the OpenStreetMap info in the answers as an alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty difficult to imagine making a navigation app without some source of map data.  An alternative to Google Map API is the OpenStreetMap API. Here is a [page on developing OpenStreetMap apps for iOS](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Apple_iOS), which includes a list of currently existing apps.  So yes, it's feasible.

Comment: can this be used in other countries too??

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was actually struggling with finding free map data.. do you recommend any others??

Comment: If you want to go the OSM way a good starting point for SDKs that you could us is http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks#Frameworks

Answer (score 1):

A large company with many resources can build this type of app.  Apple does not provide any type of API for this.  You would need a data source for your maps and a data source and algorithm to give directions.  You cannot use Google Maps directions in IOS directly.  So the answer is yes it's possible but unlikely to make any money in the app store due to the large initial investment and strong competition.

Answer (score 0):

now iOs 6.0 has replaced google map with built in maps that very easy to implement and a lot   of features are also built in